# I am receiving an error in screenshot 1 then I open the file and receive error screenshot 2

Tags: file-upload, google-bigquery, dataset

Error 1:

[image]

Error 2:

[image]

I haven't tried anything, I googled why did I get these errors and it stated to ask here. I am struggling and even looked at the module and course again. I am at the end of this Data Analytics course for a case study but need to upload the dataset to clean the data and etc.

Comment: It looks like your CSV file is invalid. Consider cutting it into pieces (using a text editor) and seeing which piece fails. An ASCII `0` byte is odd, to be honest. Where did the CSV file come from?